# CREA DDF, retrieve a single property By ID

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull one single property from the CREA Data Distribution Facility by it's listing ID. The purpose is for a wordpress plugin where the realtor will simply input his listing ID and it will pull all the data into the wordpress post.

If you've had any experience with this system, i'm using [PHPRETS](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS) and am having a hell of time navigating through the documentation for querying. I've got a feed all setup and pulling random properties, but i'm looking to pull one specific one.

Thanks! Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: What kind of data are you looking to pull specifically? Photos or listing data (like price, and other info related to the listing)?

Answer (score 2):

If you looking for the php eneral code, please try this :

1- dowload PHRets_CREA.php file from CREA website : https://support.crea.ca/DDF#/discussion/20/crea-data-distribution-code-sample-in-php.

2- create your php file in the same folder :
Of course you must have $ListingKey, change it on the code

```
/* RETS Variables */
require("PHRets_CREA.php");
$RETS = new PHRets();
$RETSURL = "http://data.crea.ca/Login.svc/Login";
$RETSUsername = "Username";
$RETSPassword = "Password";
$RETS->Connect($RETSURL, $RETSUsername, $RETSPassword);
$RETS->AddHeader("RETS-Version", "RETS/1.7.2");
$RETS->AddHeader('Accept', '/');
$RETS->SetParam('compression_enabled', true);
$RETS_LimitPerQuery = 10;
$TimeBackPull = "-1 hours";

echo 'Connecting to RETS as : <span style="color:#008000;"><b>'.$RETSUsername.'</b></span><br/>';
echo "-----GETTING ALL Listings-----<br/>";
//Get Id's
$DBML = "(LastUpdated=" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($TimeBackPull)) . ")";
$params = array("Limit" => 1, "Format" => "STANDARD-XML", "Count" => 1);
$results = $RETS->SearchQuery("Property", "Property", $DBML, $params);
$totalAvailable = $results["Count"];
echo "-----".$totalAvailable." Found-----<br/>";

$ListingKey = "ListingKey here";
$propriety = $RETS->SearchQuery("Property", "Property", "(ID=".$ListingKey.")", array("Limit" => 1, "Format" => "STANDARD-XML"));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($propriety);
echo "</pre>";
```